# Selenium IDE - what is causing this error message ("Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined")

Tags: selenium, forex

I am trying to read in a count from a webpage screen with Selenium IDE using the following code. The count increments automatically on-screen.

I am encountering an error message and I'm not sure how to resolve it - I suspect I may need to define the variable but I have been unable to figure how to do it.

```
      store value     id=eas-collection-notification      x
      echo            ${x}

      
      storeValue on id=eas-collection-notification with value x Failed:
      Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
```

Can you please advise me how to make this code work? I just want to compare the number on-screen to take a further action once it reaches a defined threshold.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you improve your question according to these guidelines? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try using `storeText` instead of `storeValue`.